# Combining multiple SOQL queries on the same object

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, soql, list-view

I have a list of SOQL queries which are used to fetch the objects associated with corresponding list views. The list views are selected manually by the user, and a generous maximum for how many I'd ever expect them to select would be 20. I'm thinking of ways to bundle all the queries together, since I know it's bad practice to loop through DML operations, but it's gotten a little tricky:

Since all the queries are fetching the same object type, I've considered just using regex to get the list of clauses after the WHERE in each query, combine them together in a string like "WHERE (queryWhereClauses[0]) OR (queryWhereClauses[1]) ..." and then inserting that at the end of my master query, which should give me a combined list of all the objects in every list view. However, I don't know how I would determine which objects in that combined list belong to which query. I can't just make a map using a certain field since we may be filtering by any number of fields. It doesn't seem feasible to try to filter the bundled query result myself since I'd have to implement all of the functionality in the SOQL filtering.

Is it acceptable to just loop through the queries anyway since it'd be rare to see more than a few of them? Alternatively, is there some way I could make it work bundling all the different queries together?

Comment: What generates the SOQL queries? Would it not be better to have separate definitions of the required columns and necessary WHERE clause terms? This would leave your code able to choose to easily merge the various parts into a single query or to use these details when generating the presentational data tables. I am wondering how you would know what records belong to which list though.

Comment: The SOQL queries are fetched through REST API calls. It does make more sense to have the column part of the query separate from the WHERE clauses, especially considering the queries as they're given are missing important columns. Unfortunately I'm not sure if it's possible to separate the records once they're retrieved.

Comment: If you need that record segregation to the individual queries then you're going to probably need to perform separate queries.